# "The reason why" versus "The reason for why": Is that "for" there required or forbidden, preferred or undesirable?

Tags: word-usage, prepositions, omissibility, reason-why

Which of the following is to be preferred, and why?

1. The reason **for** why the grass is wet is that it rained last night.
2. The reason why the grass is wet is that it rained last night.

Comment: The grass is wet because it rained last night. This seems the simplest and most elegant expression of the meaning.
I am always suspicious of "reason(s)" and "why" being next to each other. There can be reasons for things but there is usually a better way of expressing "reasons why".

Answer (score 2):

> The reason for why the grass is wet is that it rained last night.

In this sentence 'for' should be removed; then it's ok.
The reason for this is because 'why' is enough and there is no need to add 'for'. 
Why do you even need to use 'for' anyway? I don't understand!

Your second sentence is completely correct.
Use that one. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can either say

> The reason why the grass is wet is that it rained last night.

or, leaving out 'why',

> The reason the grass is wet is that it rained last night.

or, to make it more complicated, replacing 'why' with 'for a certain reason',

> The reason for which the grass is wet is that it rained last night.

Comment: How does this answer the question asking for the reason one or another verson is preferred?